# hr_err_pid documents on desktop

Tags: java, windows

When attaching documents to an email, it shows that I have more than 20 hs_err_pid documents on my desktop.  But they are not physically present on my desktop nor do they show up when I search "hs_err" in My Computer.  I only see them when I "browse" to attach something to email.  Any ideas on how to delete them?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These are dump files that are usually generated when the Java VM crashes for some reason. This should normally not happen. If you are using an older Java version, try updating it; there might be a bug that has been solved in a newer version. The reason you don't always see them might be because they are "hidden" or "system" files.

Try opening a command prompt and navigating to your desktop directory with `cd C:\Users\<yourusername>\Desktop`. Check if you can see the files where with `dir`, and try to delete them with `del`.